# Tensorflow : Update Certain Tensor Indices On a Condition

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, tensor

I am using Tensorflow and I want to apply the condition below to my `tensor`:

```
if(value > 0):
   value = log(value)
else:
   value = -log(-value)
```

Currently, I am doing the following.

```
minone = tf.constant(-1, dtype=tf.float32)
condition = tf.less(X, minone)
idx = tf.where(condition)
portion = tf.gather_nd(X, idx)
log = -tf.log(-portion)
X = tf.scatter_nd_update(X, idx, log)
```

However, this only works when `X` is of type `tf.Variable` and not of a normal `Tensor` type.

How would I achieve a working condition for a variable of `Tensor` type?

Answer (score 2):

```
value = tf.sign(value) * tf.log(tf.abs(value))
```